# Dynamic query in snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic

Suppose I have the following snowflake SQL table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
(
    col1 INT,
    col2 INT,
    condition VARCHAR
);
 
INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, condition)
VALUES (5, 10, 'col1 < col2'),
       (20, 15, 'col1 > col2'),
       (20, 30, 'col1 > col2');
```

I want to run the string in column "condition" and write its boolean result in a new column called "result." Thanks!

I tried using running command `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on each row but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you put the code you have that isn't working? As well as the fully formed static query(s) you want the dynamic procedure to create.

Comment: Are < and > the only operators? And is Col1 always before Col2 in the condition?

Comment: Please update your question with the complete SQL that you’ve managed to write. Can you also explain what you mean by ‘ run the string in column "condition"’? What would ‘running’ 'col1 < col2' actually look like?

Comment: you have space before and after (< and >) operators in every row? and secondly is there any primary key or unique key column present in you table?

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? The following update statement would work with a couple assumptions on the order of the condition. `update table set result = case when condition like '%>%' then col1 > col2 else col1 < col2 end`